# Probability and source emission.

Tags: probability

I am not sure how does probability enter in this question, but anyway:

> "A source emits particles at an average K particles per second. Each
> emission is stochastically independent of the previous emission.
> Calculate the probability that exactly n particles will be emitted
> within a time interval t"

I just thought that it could be: $P(n) = \frac{n}{\int_{0}^{t} K dt}$. But i am not sure how does the stochastically independence enter in my answer.

Stochasticaly independence means independent events.

Comment: What assumptions do you make on the distribution of the emission?

Answer (score 1):

The common way here is to assume that the particles emitted follow a poisson law $Po(k)$ per second.
This assumption is reasonable observing that is also reasonable that increasing the number of particles per second the probability tends to decrease ( i.e., the probability to observe k particles is assumed greater than observing 4k particles).

Thus the requested probability is

$$\mathbb{P}[X=n]=\frac{e^{-kt}(kt)^n}{n!}$$

Where

- $n=0,1,2\dots$
- $t$ is expressed in seconds

Stochastic independence implies that $\sum_{i=1}^t X_i\sim Po(kt)$

---

This if the particles are few (law of rare events); if $kt$ becomes large the distribution can be approximated with a gaussian $N(kt;kt)$